# How do you 'require' external modules in Electron with the new, secure, default settings?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, require, sandbox

I have an Electron app from several years back that I'm trying to update to use the latest versions of Node, Electron, and all the external modules I've used. It's been a very frustrating experience as all the paradigms have shifted, especially around security, but I want to keep my app using the secure settings if possible.

From my understanding, the relevant default settings for Electron (I am using version 16.0.5) are

```
nodeIntegration: false
contextIsolation: true
sandbox: true
```

Here's what I have in my createWindow block:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1280,
      height: 720,
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html');

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}
```

As you can see, I am not changing the defaults at all. This is desired, following the [security instructions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) from the Electron website.

However, I've been completely unable to restore previous functionality of my app due to this. The biggest problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to `require` any external dependencies at all. As far as I understand it, the preload file can only require specific Electron modules, and normal renderer JavaScript files cannot require anything at all (you get a `require() is not defined` error). From what I understand from the documentation, the `main.js` file has normal `require` access and you are meant to use `ipc` to communicate between `main.js` and `preload.js` so that only your main process has full access to remote modules.

That's fine and dandy, except I can't even `require` anything in `main.js` leaving me extremely confused:

```
// in main.js
const google = require('googleapis');
```

> ```
> App threw an error during load
> Error: Cannot find module 'googleapis'
> ```

I've made sure I've `yarn install`ed properly, have tried with different modules, changed the ordering, etc. I also have not been able to find a *single example* online of someone using the new default security settings but using `require` for external modules. Every single one of them uses `require` for built-in things and the `preload.js` file examples, either from Google or the official documentation, just show how you can expose basic built in stuff like `window` and `document` calls using `preload.js` which really isn't all that helpful.

So is it just not possible? I have to wonder what in the world the point of a Node/Electron app that can't use any public Node modules is, so if the default security settings preclude you from having an app that provides any sort of useful functionality, I don't know why they are the defaults. What am I missing? How can I get back to using external modules like `googleapis` and `ffmpeg` without disabling these apparently critical security features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason I was having 'Cannot find module' errors was because I was using Yarn with `pnp`. Electron doesn't support packages not in the `node_modules` folder, see [discussion on Yarn GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/discussions/3897) and [semi-confirmation of issue on Electron GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31611#issuecomment-958945988)

Switching to `nodelinker: node-modules` or `nodelinker: pnpm` to `.yarnrc.yml` in place of `nodelinker: pnp` solves it.

This still only partially helps me as I have to figure out how to allow sandboxed renderers and preloads access to external module methods, but it's a starting point and solves my initial frustration of "wait--you can't require *anything* external?"